# c# Remove html body's numeric symbol code from html agility pack inner text

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I would like to know if there are any ways to remove  numeric symbol codes(such as &#91) from inner text retrieved from site node using html agility pack.

Programming language: C#

Below is the code i used to get the inner-text:

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb web = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb();
            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmlDocument = web.Load(result[0]/* Here comes the url of a wikipedia's page */);
            result_title.Text = result[1];
            result_content.Text = "";
            for (int i = 2; i <= 4; i++)
            {
                try
                {
                    foreach (var item in htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div[5]/div[1]/p["+i+"]"))
                    {
                        result_content.Text += item.InnerText;
                    }
                }
                catch (NullReferenceException)
                {
                    result_content.Text = "This is a content page. Please refer the url";
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            System.Windows.Documents.Hyperlink hyperlink = new System.Windows.Documents.Hyperlink
            {
                NavigateUri = new Uri("" + result[0]),

            };
            hyperlink.Inlines.Add("Read More...");
            hyperlink.RequestNavigate += Hyperlink_RequestNavigate;
            result_content.Inlines.Add(hyperlink);
            Search_Progress.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            selected_result_scroll.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
```

The output is below:

[image: output]

As you can see in the image, it consists of the output of the inner-text grabbed from the wikipedia page's body. I like to know if there is any way i can remove those numeric symbolic code from it(the one's marked in red around it).

The text shown in wikipedia site is below(if you want to know what do those codes show in web):

> Ambareesha is a 2014 Indian Kannada-language action film directed and produced by Mahesh Sukhadhare under the Sri Sukhadhare Pictures banner.[1][2] The film stars Darshan, Rachita Ram and Priyamani. Dr.Ambareesh and his wife Sumalatha Ambareesh will be seen in guest roles.[3] The soundtrack and score is composed by V. Harikrishna and the cinematography is by Ramesh Babu.

Comment: It is better to show sample code and it's output . Also mention your desired output/result explicitly . That way will helpful for the community to understand the issue. And show your research effort such as the related info you've got from documentations or alternative sample code which didn't work

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.